# Написание слова

Tags: падежи

Как написать в родительном падеже "ревизор-инспектор"?

Comment: У вас есть вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ревизору-инспектору.

Comment: Это дательный падеж, а не родительный.

Comment: ладно, простите, тогда так: ревизора-инспектора. Суть не в падежах, а в том, что склоняются оба слова

Answer (score 1):

В родительном падеже: **ревизора-инспектора**.

Comment: А генерал-майор?

Comment: Генерал-майора. Генерал-майор - воинское звание, нечто устоявшееся, воспринимаемое как неразрывная единица.  "Генерал-майор" - не то же самое, что "генерал и майор", а вот ревизор-инспектор - это ревизор и инспектор.